# External JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript

I'm using JS for the first time. Can't seem to call an external JS function at all. I have a HTML form and im trying to call a function so if the first name box is empty, I get a message saying to fill in a name.

My form

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/validation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="myForm" method="post" action="somewhere.html" 
   onsubmit="validation()">

<fieldset id="PersonalDetails">
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    <div class="form" id="firstname">
    <p>First Name: <br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    </p>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
```

In the JS file:

```
 function validation(){
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
 {
 alert("First name must be filled out!!!!");
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Open up your developer console (usually F12 does it, but it varies) - do you see any errors? If you're a new dev, I can't stress the importance of the console enough, it's your best friend.

Comment: I don't see anything, but I don't know what im looking for. I'm just wondering how to call the funtion correctly. I know how to do it if the JS is in the HTML file, but not for an external js file

Comment: You're function call works, see jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ej7tY/

Answer (score 2):

you need to have a submit button in your form trigger the onsubmit event. Your function will be called if you've imported your javascript correctly. See below you're form with a submit button.

```
<body>
 <form name="myForm" method="post" action="somewhere.html" 
   onsubmit="validation()">

<fieldset id="PersonalDetails">
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    <div class="form" id="firstname">
    <p>First Name: <br />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    </p>
        <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `onsubmit="validation()"` to `onsubmit="return validation()"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change your form

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="validation()">
```

change your javascript

```
function validation(){
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;
 if (x==null || x==""){
     alert("First name must be filled out!!!!");
     return false;
 }else{
    document.forms["myForm"].setAttribute("action", "somewhere.html").submit();
 }
}
```